# Is WebRtc library provide snapshot features?

Tags: android, webrtc

I have to snapshot the live streaming video using webrtc. How can I snap the view?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `canvas` and `video` tags and `context.drawImage`. For a detailed tutorial please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos